# Mandelbrot Set area

Tags: area, infinity, fractals, complex-dynamics

If there are an infinite amount of details that can be found in a Mandelbrot set, shouldn't the Mandelbrot Set have an infinite area? Supposedly the area of a Mandelbrot set is 1.5065918849 ± 0.0000000028 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_constants_and_functions).

Comment: The boundary is very complicated, and even two-dimensional. However, the interior of the set is finite, since it's contained in the disc of radius two, centred at the origin. That means that if you want to put up a fence around your Mandelbrot shaped sheep pen, you would need a _lot_ of fence, but if you want to sow grass inside it, you don't need many packs of seeds.

Comment: The Mandelbrot set is contained in the disc $|z|\leq2$. Hopefully you can see that its area must be less than the area of this disc.

Comment: A [Koch Snowflake](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Koch_snowflake) has similar properties - an infinite perimeter but finite area

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Mandelbrot set can't have infinite area, since the entire set is contained in the disk of radius $2$ centered at the origin.